# how to prevent the manual shutdown or Reboot to set the passwd even though login as root

Tags: passwd

I have given the reboot command unexpectedly,to prevent this issue need to assign password confirmation for shutdown or reboot activities even though logging as root.Kindly suggest to prevent this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A solution for your request was found [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23772525/reboot-shutdown-y-n-confirmation-message-before-proceeding.html)

In the root .bash_profile, setup two aliases like:

```
alias shutdown='/usr/local/bin/confirm shutdown'
alias reboot='/usr/local/bin/confirm reboot'
```

With `/usr/local/bin/confirm` being something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Before proceeding to perform $1, please ensure you have approval to perform this task"
echo -n "Would you like to proceed y/n? "
read reply

if [ "$reply" = y -o "$reply" = Y ]
then
   /sbin/$1
else
   echo "$1 cancelled"
fi
```

> Notes:
>
> - You can replace the `y` respond with your password
> - You can use [shell-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shc_the_shell_script_compiler) to replace the shell script with a compiled code which won't expose the password

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be a password?

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/molly-guard.8.html

> molly-guard was primarily designed to shield SSH connections. This
>          functionality (which should arguably be provided by the openssh-server
>          package) is implemented in /etc/molly-guard/run.d/30-query-hostname.
>
> This script first tests whether the command is being executed from a
>          tty which has been created by sshd. It also checks whether the variable
>          SSH_CONNECTION is defined. If any of these tests are successful, test
>          script queries the user for the machine's hostname, which should be
>          sufficient to prevent the user from doing something by accident.

and

> setting ALWAYS_QUERY_HOSTNAME
>          in /etc/molly-guard/rc causes the script to always query.